# can anyone please explain in details what is happening in this code,i am stuck

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

can anyone please explain in details what is happening in this code, i am stuck

```
Column(
  children: [
    Question(
      questions[_questionIndex]['questionText'],
    ),
    ...(questions[_questionIndex]['answers'] as List<String>)
        .map((answer) {
      return Answer(_answerQuestion, answer);
    }).toList()
  ],
)
```

please help me , thanks in advance

Comment: check this [codelab](https://dart.dev/codelabs/iterables)  ([mapping](https://dart.dev/codelabs/iterables#mapping) section in particular)

Answer (score 0):

```
Column( 
  children: [ 
    Question( questions[_questionIndex]['questionText'], ), ...   

    ( // I guess this brace should not be here

     questions[_questionIndex]['answers'] as List).map((answer) { 
        return Answer(_answerQuestion, answer); 
     }).toList() 
  ], 
)
```

so the Column exists of a Question widget and some Answer widgets. Do you need more details?